# Remove component specific version from bit.dev

Tags: reactjs, components, bit.dev

While developing a component sometimes we push the changes to the scope (bit export) so we can import and test the changes on other projects, these versions are useless (e.g: 0.0.0-test.1), so we clean them up after finishing working with the component. We'd to have a way of cleaning those test versions using bit remove component_name --ver 1.1.0 -r

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do but I think it will be better if you [snap](https://bit.dev/docs/components/snaps) changes instead of tagging a new version and maybe even use a [lane](https://bit.dev/docs/lanes/lanes-overview). Give it a try and tell me how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In `Bit,` you tag your new versions incrementally. That follows the [Semver](https://semver.org/) conventions.

No need to `delete` older versions; use the newer ones.
But if so you can [`deprecate it`](https://bit.dev/docs/components/removing-components). Deprecating is a nondestructive way to flag an outdated version.

Now, that put aside, you can always open a new developing [`lane`](https://bit.dev/docs/lanes/lanes-overview). A `lane` is like a git branch. It bifurcates from the original path and allows for diverging. Once you are satisfied with the diverge, you can merge it back:

```
bit lane merge new-feature
```

Conclusion: you shouldn't delete versions. Create newer ones or depreacate. If what you want is to diverge from the main developing line, use `bit lane`. You can always merge it back.